# Can't access Windows 2000 UNC path anymore

Tags: windows, unc

For a long time, we've been able to access our Windows 2000 server using this method:

\10.0.0.18\d$   (typed in winexplorer)  ... and here we enter an adminusers username/password and gain access..

But all of a sudden, we can no longer access it. Ive checked the users on the server, they are not locked out or anything. I've tried restarting the server, but It didn't help.

Event viewer on server gives 2 eventid 529s:
Login Failure:
Reason: Unknown user name or bad password

and
The logon to account: administrator
by: MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0
from workstation: blabla
failed. The error code was: 3221225578

- Ive checked the errorcode, it means the user does not exist.. weird!! :-(

... I can't understand why it says this - even if I create a new user for the occation, this is what it says.. It's like the server can't find any of the users.

Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it was because of the clock on the server ... This post helped me:

https://serverfault.com/questions/249434/access-denied-error-3221225578-with-file-sharing-to-windows-server